# Need to read an image in node js

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I need to read an image in node js. In python code

```py
with open(path, 'rb') as f:
  contents = f.read()
```

This code gives me correct output. How can I implement the same read function in node js.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v17.x/docs/api/fs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this link [reading files with node.js](https://nodejs.dev/learn/reading-files-with-nodejs) will help you. If you want to manage a file (can be image, audio, video, txt etc.), you can use the [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) module of node.js.